# Codename One Inverted QR Scanning

Tags: codenameone, qr-code

We are building an app that allow the user to scan a QR Code that has been engraved into a plastic lid.
The engraved QR Code is inverted as the plastic lid is black and the QR Code is white.

So I have two questions,

1. Is there a flag or something that we can pass into the scanning library to inform it that we will be scanning inverted QR codes?
2. How would one go about debugging the issue to find what we (or the library) this doing wrong?

Here is the code we are using to do the scannnig,

```
                Display.getInstance().unlockOrientation();
                CodeScanner.getInstance().scanQRCode(new com.codename1.ext.codescan.ScanResult() {

                    @Override
                    public void scanCompleted(String string, String string1, byte[] bytes) {
                        txtBarcode.setText(string);
                        Display.getInstance().lockOrientation(true);

                        ScanClaim.this.revalidate();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void scanCanceled() {
                        EMCDialogFactory.showMessageDialog("Cancelled", "Scan Cancelled");
                        Display.getInstance().lockOrientation(true);

                        ScanClaim.this.revalidate();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void scanError(int i, String string) {
                        EMCDialogFactory.showMessageDialog("Error", string);
                        Display.getInstance().lockOrientation(true);

                        ScanClaim.this.revalidate();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be hard with the standard QR scanner as it's a standalone library with not many options there. You can debug the native implementation but here you're also running into a problem because the default implementation of QR scanner relies on the user having a 3rd party scanner app.

There's the little monkey version of the qr scanner: https://github.com/littlemonkeyltd/QRScanner/
It's embedded in and might work better/worse. Debugging it is a pain. Notice this only applies to Android and in iOS it will use the standard zbar that we use in the main QR scanner.

If you can afford it there's the Scandit cn1lib: https://github.com/shannah/cn1-codescan-scandit

It's a pretty hefty license fee but they would probably work with any QR/bar code you have.